# How to prevent an application from being able to automatically open webbrowser in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser

I am using a free anti internet censorship application under windows 10 witch connects me to another network.
Every single time witch i run this application , after it successfully connects to the network, then automatically opens my default web browser and show's up a random webpage based on its own choices.

**I want to know how i can limit this windows application from being able to open the the default web browser. I want to continue using this application  and at the same time restrict it's ability to open and show links in my browser.**

Any trick through windows is superior for me than using 3rd party tools to overcome this issue.

Comment: You can’t.  How it’s opening the browser is the same way you would start the application. It’s likely using the Win32 or UWP API calls.

Comment: I don't exactly follow you, but I would run Process Monitor and filter for "Process Create" operations.  From there you should see the event where process a has launched process b.  The command line and stack should help you understand how process a launched process b.